# Good idea to have an index on datetime column?

Tags: sql-server, index

Assuming something like so:

`select * from table where DatePart(YEAR, dateColumn) = 2012`

Reasonable to have  an index on dateColumn?

Edit*

For **SQLServer**

Comment: What DBMS are we talking about? The answer may be different for each.

Comment: What is the date datatype you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding an index is definitely a good idea for this.  However, DATEPART(YEAR, datecolumn) = 2012 isnt' sargable so it will still do a scan of the index.

If you want it to use the index then you will need to do:

```
WHERE dateColumn >= '1/1/2012' AND dateColumn < '1/1/2013'
```

Please note the placement of the >= and the < signs to get the correct bounding box.